# In block getModel error?

Tags: extensions, magento2, overrides, backend

I have Block 
question

> class Question extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
>   implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface

in function

```
public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Mageaddons\Productquestion\Model\ProductquestionFactory  $productQuestion, 
        \Mageaddons\Productquestion\Model\AnswerquestionFactory  $answersQuestion, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $product,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_productQuestion = $productQuestion;
        $this->_answersQuestion = $answersQuestion;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }
```

when run get error

```
[2015-12-04 08:20:22] main.CRITICAL: Circular dependency: Mageaddons\Productquestion\Block\Product\Question depends on Mageaddons\Productquestion\Block\Product\Question and vice versa. [] []
```

any help. tks!

**Edited**
when i comment

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $product,
```

**it work.**
This block be use to add in Product View.
.So how do get **custommer** isLoggedIn and **product** in product view.

Comment: did you clear your cache and var/generation directory after updating to latest code base?

Comment: yes but get error same.

Comment: check Circular Dependency Error in magento2 [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84545/circular-dependency-error-in-magento2)

Comment: I edited my question @MineshPatel